# How to use custom score functions in bnlearn version 4.6?

Tags: r, bnlearn

bnlearn 4.6 has support for custom decomposable scores according to the [changelog](http://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/changelog.html). I can't figure out how to use it though. I've tried `net <- hc(df, score = "custom")` and it gives me `Error in check.custom.score.function(fun = extra.args$fun): missing the custom score function`. Anyone know how to feed the custom function to `hc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out from `bnlearn:::check.score.args`. You need to provide a `fun` argument, so something like `net <- hc(df, score = "custom", fun=function(...) ...)`. Just for reference, the function signature is `function(node, parents, data, args)`.